# Running integration tests with springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-test-mvc

I have several heavy Spring integration tests (yeah, it's not the best approach and I'm running out of time to mock all external deps properly)

Here is typical annotation of a test

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@EmbeddedKafka(
        partitions = 1,
        brokerProperties = {"log.dir=target/${random.int}/embedded-kafka/data"},
        topics = {
                "${service.topic}",
                "${service.dead-letter-topic}"
        })
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class OneOfMyHeavyintegrationTests extends DatabaseBackedTest {

// omitted for brevity
//
}

// foundation for DB in tests
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = DatabaseBackedTest.Initializer.class)
public abstract class DatabaseBackedTest {

    private static final EmbeddedPostgresInfo db = EmbeddedPostgresDatabase.create().start();

    static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
            TestPropertyValues.of("spring.datasource.url=" + db.getJdbcUrl()).applyTo(context.getEnvironment());
        }
    }

}
```

Tests periodically fail due to

```
22:14:51.462  [main] INFO  o.a.k.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 2.0.1 
22:14:51.463  [main] INFO  o.a.k.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : fa14705e51bd2ce5 
22:14:51.466  [main] WARN  o.a.k.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Error registering AppInfo mbean 
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: kafka.server:type=app-info,id=0
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:436)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1855)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:955)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:890)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:320)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser.registerAppInfo(AppInfoParser.java:62)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:321)
    at kafka.utils.TestUtils$.createServer(TestUtils.scala:132)
    at kafka.utils.TestUtils.createServer(TestUtils.scala)
```

There are two questions:
1. what is the right way to make tests co-exist together? I set `forkCount=0` in surefire plugin. It seemed to help

2. what is the right way to `mock` / `disable` components before starting tests?

2.1. I don't really need to start all my `@Scheduled` `@Component` during every tests

2.2. I don't really need to start Kafka consumers at every test

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run several tests with kafka you can use [DirtiesContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html) annotation on your test class. this will tell spring that this test does things that might collide with others and needs to be cleaned. you should put it on each class that uses kafka (on this error)

If you have components of your system that you don't need on these tests, use [MockBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) annotation to replace them with mocks when the server starts